# Query for json column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Firstly I stored my JSON in a `varchar` column, now I got a requirement to change on of the fields in the JSON. How to retrieve the field and update it?

Example of one record

```json
{ "name": "Bob", isSelected: "true" }
```

True needs to be changed to false

Comment: Does your JSON data *really* have smart quotes in it? SQL Server won't be able to parse that.

Comment: Yes only for true false it doesn’t have

Answer (score 2):

*If* your JSON is properly formatted (it's not in your question as `isSelected` isn't quoted), then you use can `JSON_MODIFY`:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"name": "Bob", "isSelected":"true" }';
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.isSelected', 'false');
```

If it isn't properly formatted, fix your process that creates the JSON first, to create well formed JSON, and then use `JSON_MODIFY`.

Comment: It is showing json_modify is not recognised as built in function

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using, @madinenisravani ? `JSON_MODIFY` is available in all fully supported versions of SQL Server and 2016. If you are getting that error, that likely means you're using a *much* older version of SQL Server; this is something you *need* to tell us as otherwise it will be assumed you are using (fully) supported software. If you *are* using SQL Server 2014 or prior I suggest that you either upgrade, or you do this outside of SQL Server, as 2014 and prior have **no** JSON support.

Comment: Yes we are using older version Is there anyother option to get by using regex

Comment: T-SQL has no support for Regex, @madinenisravani . As I mentioned, if you're using a not (fully) supported of SQL Server, then your options are really either: 1. Upgrade. 2. Parse the JSON outside of SQL Server.